# Deliver data in local storage on Windows 8

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to send some data already in the local storage in an Windows 8 app? I'm using a file based database in my project and want to deliever the whole database to the user so that I don't have to create all entries (more than 350).

You can find the data of the local storage in C:\Users\ *username*\AppData\Local\Packages, but there I cannot save information out of my app. Perhaps you have an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it in the past, to allow writing data to the file was...

- Add the file as an asset.
- on startup, check the local storage folder to see if the file exists.
- If the file doesn't exist, copy it from the InstalledLocation to LocalFolder
- perform IO as normal on the copied file.

If you then need to update the file from the web, you can download the new copy direct to the LocalFolder path for use, or parse it and add entries to the original file.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you tell me how I can copy a file to the local folder?

Comment: Have a look at the file access sample here -> http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597

Comment: If your data is large you maybe won't add it as an asset but download the data on application start to reduce the filesize of your windows store package.