# When I deploy windows store app, I want a file to be placed at ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. How to?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

When I deploy windows store app, I want a file to be placed at ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder so that I can read that file from ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.

How to do it?

**The problem actually is that I place my file at ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, I know where this file is located in my computer. Then I read from this location in my app. But when I upload this to windows store, the app cannot find the file at: ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. Please please please help me with this!!!**

Comment: Related: [Deliver data in local storage on Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514220/deliever-data-in-local-storage-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 1):

The app can only deploy files to its install directory, not to its application data. Instead you can copy the file from the install direction on first run the first time the file is needed.